# JCheckBox sizing & firing actions

Tags: java, swing, action, jmenu, jmenuitem

I'm having some issues firing an action from a JCheckBox:

```
JMenu topMenu = new JMenu("Top Menu");

MyAction action1 = new MyAction("Action1");
MyAction action2 = new MyAction("A2");

JCheckBox checkBox1 = new JCheckBox( action1 );
JCheckBox checkBox2 = new JCheckBox( action2 );

topMenu.add( checkBox1 );
topMenu.add( checkBox2 );
```

When mousing over the topMenu, it expands and shows the JCheckBoxes labeled "Action1" and "A2".
Clicking on the checkbox or the text toggles the checkbox.

This part is a little hard to explain: There's an area to the right of "A2" that's empty - since "Action1" takes up more space, then the submenu that is displayed when hovering on topMenu will be the width of "Action1". The "A2" row will be the same width, but only the checkbox and "A2" fire the action.

Clicking to the right of the "A2" text doesn't do anything.
How might I go about fixing this in the simplest way possible?

Comment: for better help sooner, please include an [sscce](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 5):

Don't add JCheckBoxes to menus. Instead use the menu variant: [JCheckBoxMenuItem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBoxMenuItem.html). The [menu tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) will explain how to use these.

e.g.,

```
JMenu topMenu = new JMenu("Top Menu");

MyAction action1 = new MyAction("Action1");
MyAction action2 = new MyAction("A2");

JCheckBoxMenuItem checkBox1 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem( action1 );
JCheckBoxMenuItem checkBox2 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem( action2 );

topMenu.add( checkBox1 );
topMenu.add( checkBox2 );
```

Comment: I had actually tried this but had a little problem. Do the checkboxes in the JCheckBoxMenuItem's show up way smaller for you guys? (And there's a bug in the java version we're using that's preventing me from setting the sizeVariant property for the JComponent to "regular". Unfortunately I can't change the java version.)